# How to do partial regression plots with linear mixed-effect models?

Tags: r, mixed-model, data-visualization, lme4-nlme, partial-effect

I have a linear mixed-effect model in R with two continuous fixed-effects and one random effect, like this:

```
                           model<-lmer(y~x1+x2+(1|r),data)
```

To graphically display the independent effect of `x1` on `y`, while controlling the effects of `x2` (fixed effect) and `r` (random effect), is it appropriate to do a partial regression plot using the same logic used for multiple linear regression models? I.e.:

```
                          #removing the effect of x2 and r on y

                         res.y<-residuals(lmer(y~x2+(1|r),data)) 

                          #removing the effect of x2 and r on x1

                         res.x1<-residuals(lmer(x1~x2+(1|r),data)) 

              #partial regression plot to display the pure effect of x1 on y

                                     plot(res.x1,res.y)
```

Also, I used the       "plotLMER.fnc function"  from the "LMERConvenienceFunctions" R package to plot the partial effect size of each fixed effect as follows:

```
                                      plotLMER.fnc(model)
```

However, I am not sure what this package means by "effect size". Is it β1 and β2?

I will be very grateful for any help in this issue.

Comment: You might be better on an R-specific site like R-help or asking the package maintainer.

Comment: Please provide some example data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **[`remef`](https://github.com/hohenstein/remef)** package to prepare data for the visualization of partial effects. The package can be installed with `devtools`.

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("hohenstein/remef")
```

To remove the influece of `x2` and the random effects from the dependent variable, you can use

```
library(remef)
y_partial <- remef(model, fix = "x2", ran = "all")
```

This will create a modified version of `y` based on the partial effect while the residuals are still present. Hence, you can still visualize the deviations from the predictions.

With the adjusted data `y_partial` you can, for example, create a plot of `y_partial` as a function of `x1` together with a linear regression line.

---

Disclaimer: I am the author of the `remef` package

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot! Is there a code to compute the partial R^2?

Comment: @tomzer I'm sorry, I don't have a solution for this paricular task.

Answer (score 6):

I used the Effect function from the [effect package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/effects/index.html) for this.

```
model1<-lmer(y~x1+x2+(1|r),data)

est<-Effect("x1", partial.residuals=T, model1)
plot(est)
```

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated @Seraina! Try improving the quality of your answer by explaining why your proposed solution is the right answer and how it works to make it as useful as possible for others who might be struggling with the same problem.

Comment: This answer is totally perfect, clear and helpful, no need for clutter it with unnecessary bs. Good job Seraina!

Comment: @Seraina, is this a partial plot where the effects of other variables in the model are held at 0? Or are they controlled for in some other way? So basically it's plots the coefficient of x1 from the lmer?